# Can an eclipse view contribute to the application menu?

Tags: eclipse, view, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm creating a simple eclipse application which will contain only views. I've chosen to use only views so users can arrange and stack their views however they like (since editors and views cannot be stacked together).  There also isn't any need for a traditional "editor" and I don't want the editor space always showing.  But, enough about my decision to use only views.

I was wondering if there is a way for a view to contribute to the main menu for the application?  For example, can switching views cause the main application menu to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`org.eclipse.ui.menus`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_cmd_menus.htm) extension point and set your command to only be visible when the view is active.